# Single Server UDP Broadcast, MultipleClients UDP in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have created single server and single client echo application. It works fine for single server and single client. But now I want to make it more practical by handling multiple clients for a single server.

Below is my functional code. How can I modify it to make a single server multiple clients application?

**Server:**

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 65507 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int idSocket, puerto;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in cliente;
    const int broadcastEnable=1;
    char name[30];
    char bufferRec[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    char bufferEnv[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    int rcb=0, envio =0;
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Ingresa el puerto/n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    puerto = atoi(argv[1]);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(puerto);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.255");
   
    idSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(idSocket == -1){
        printf("No se pudo crear el socket/n");
    }
    if(setsockopt(idSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,(char*)&broadcastEnable,sizeof(broadcastEnable)) == -1){
        printf("No se pudo crear el broadcast/n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(bind(idSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1){
        printf("Error en el bind()\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(1){
        socklen_t tam = sizeof(cliente);
        if((rcb=recvfrom(idSocket,bufferRec,sizeof(bufferRec),0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliente,&tam))==-1){
            printf("Error en el recv()\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("El cliente envio: %s\n",bufferRec);
        cliente.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
        strcpy(bufferEnv,"Hola desde el server");
        if((envio=sendto(idSocket,bufferEnv,sizeof(bufferEnv),0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliente,sizeof(cliente)))==-1){
            perror("Error en el sendto()\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Enviamos: %s\n",bufferEnv);
    }
    close(idSocket);
}
```

**Client:**

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 65507 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int idSocket, puerto, puerto_server;
    char name[30];
    int rcb=0;
    int envio;
    struct sockaddr_in server; 
    struct sockaddr_in cliente;
    char bufferRec[BUFFER_SIZE];
    const int broadcastEnable=1; 
    char bufferEnv[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Ingresa el puerto del servidor/n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    
    puerto = atoi(argv[1]);
    puerto_server = atoi(argv[2]);
   
    memset((char*)&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(puerto_server);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.255");
    
    cliente.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliente.sin_port = htons(puerto);
    cliente.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    idSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(idSocket == -1){
        printf("No se pudo crear el socket\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(setsockopt(idSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,(char*)&broadcastEnable,sizeof(broadcastEnable)) == -1){
        printf("No se pudo crear el broadcast/n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(bind(idSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&cliente, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1){
        printf("Error en el bind()\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(1){
        
        strcpy(bufferEnv,"Hola desde el cliente");
        if((envio=sendto(idSocket,bufferEnv,sizeof(bufferEnv),0,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server)))==-1){
            perror("Error en el sendto()\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Enviamos: %s\n",bufferEnv);
        socklen_t tam = sizeof(server);
        if((rcb=recvfrom(idSocket,bufferRec,sizeof(bufferRec),0,(struct sockaddr*)&server,&tam))==-1){
            printf("Error en el recv()\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("El servidor envio: %s\n",bufferRec);
    }
    close(idSocket);
}
```

Comment: Your server already handles receiving packets from multiple clients. But why is it broadcasting every packet received back out over the whole network? In a true echo server, you should send back only to the client that you received from. And you can do that by simply removing the `cliente.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;` statement.

Comment: if I want all my clients to receive the same packages at the same time?

Comment: if that is what you really want, then I don't see what the actual problem is. Your original code already does what you are asking for.

Comment: You should use multicast. Broadcast has been deprecated for 25 years if not 30.

Comment: @user207421 I can't find any evidence that IPv4 broadcast has been officially deprecated.  Do you know of any?  (btw I do agree that multicast should be used instead whenever possible)

Comment: Thank you! I was finally able to solve it.

Comment: @user207421 IPv4 broadcasting is not deprecated, any more than IPv4 itself is deprecated. It is just that in modern networks, IPv6/multicasting is *preferred*. Unicast Broadcasting doesn't exist in IPv6, but IPv4 is still heavily used in private networks.